# How to add Total amount of order form to Shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have prepared online order form for a printing house. In the form everything works smoothly. But I need to put total amount of each order into shopping cart, because someone may want to order several print jobs. I am new in javascript, I tried to do it by the loop, but it adds only once. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
//calculation script omitted
var addToCartButton = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart')
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButton.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButton[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var grandTotal = new Array;
    grandTotal.push(allTotal)
    var cartRowContents = '<table><tr><th>Xidmet adi</th><th>Cemi</th></tr>'
    var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('cartTotal')
    var serviceName = document.getElementById('service')
    for (k = 0; k < grandTotal.length; k++) {
      cartRowContents += '<tr><td>' + serviceName.value + '</td><td>' + grandTotal[k] + '</td></tr>'
    }
    buttonClicked.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    cartRowContents += '</table>'
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Onlayn ödəmə</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form class="form-payment" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" id="payment">
    <fieldset>
      <p class="warning" id="warning">Hörmətli müştəri, istəyinizə uyğun sifarişinizi qeyd edin və yekun məbləğin doğruluğundan əmin olduqdan sonra "Təsdiq et" düyməsini sıxın</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" />
      <label for="service">Xidmət növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="service" name="service" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Xidmət növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Çap'>Çap</option>
        <option value='Kserokopiya'>Kserokopiya</option>
        <option value='Kitab çapı'>Kitab çapı</option>
        <option value='Diplom və sertifikat çapı'>Diplom və sertifikat çapı</option>
        <option value='Poster çapı'>Poster çapı</option>
        <option value='Skan'>Skan </option>
        <option value='Laminasiya'>Laminasiya</option>
        <option value='Cildləmə'>Cildləmə</option>
      </select>
      <label id="papertypeL" for="papertype">Kağız növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="papertype" name="papertype" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Kağız növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Standart kağız (A4-parlaq)-0.50 AZN'>Standart kağız(A4-parlaq)-0.50 AZN</option>
        <option value='Premium kağız (A4-parlaq)-1 AZN'>Premium kağız (A4-parlaq)-1 AZN</option>
        <option value='VİP kağız (A4-Mat)-1.50 AZN'>VİP kağız (A4-Mat)-1.50 AZN</option>
      </select>
      <label id="scansizeL" for="scansize">Kağız ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="scansize" name="scansize" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>
        <option value='A4'>A4</option>
        <option value='A3'>A3</option>
      </select>
      <label id="bookprintL" for="bookprint">Kağız ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="bookprint" name="bookprint" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>
        <option value='A4'>A4</option>
        <option value='A5'>A5</option>
      </select>
      <label id="postersizeL" for="postersize">Poster ölçüsü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="postersize" name="postersize" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Ölçünü seçin</option>
        <option value='A3'>A3</option>
        <option value='A3+'>A3+</option>
      </select>
      <label id="posterpaperL" for="posterpaper">Kağız növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="posterpaper" name="posterpaper" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Kağız növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Standart kağız'>Standart kağız</option>
        <option value='Premium kağız'>Premium kağız</option>
        <option value='VİP kağız'>VİP kağız</option>
      </select>
      <label id="printL" for='print'>Çap növü:</label>
      <label id="radio" class="container-radio">Ağ-qara
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="capnovu" value="Ağ-qara" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="radio" class="container-radio">Rəngli
      <input type="radio" name="capnovu" value="Rəngli" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="sideL" for='side'>Üz sayı:</label>
      <label id="side" class="container-radio">Təküzlü
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="uzsayi" value="Təküzlü" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="side" class="container-radio">İkiüzlü
      <input type="radio"  name="uzsayi" value="İkiüzlü" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="kitab-cildL" class="container-radio" for="kitab-cild">Cildləmə<input id="kitab-cild" type="checkbox" onclick="calculateTotal()" /><span class="checkmark-box"></span></label>
      <label id="cildL" for="cild">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cild" name="cild" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kleylə cildləmə'>Kleylə cildləmə</option>
      </select>
      <label id="cildA4L" for="cildA4">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cildA4" name="cildA4" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kleylə cildləmə'>Kleylə cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Kitab bərpa'>Kitab bərpa</option>
        <option value='Çubuqla cildləmə'>Çubuqla cildləmə</option>
      </select>
      <label id="cildA3L" for="cildA3">Cildləmə növü:</label>
      <select class="form-select" id="cildA3" name="cildA3" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="none" selected disabled>Cildləmə növünü seçin</option>
        <option value='Dəmir spiral cildləmə'>Dəmir spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Plasmas spiral cildləmə'>Plasmas spiral cildləmə</option>
        <option value='Çubuqla cildləmə'>Çubuqla cildləmə</option>
      </select>
      <label id="sayL" for="say">Səhifə Sayı:</label><input id="say" name="say" class="form-input" type="text" value="" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      <label id="nusxeSayL" for="nusxeSay">Nüsxə Sayı:</label><input id="nusxeSay" name="nusxeSay" class="form-input" type="text" value="" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
      <label id="laminasiyaL" class="container-radio">Laminasiya olacaq?
      <input type="checkbox" id="laminasiya"  name="checkbox"  onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark-box"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="deliveryL" class="container-radio">Çatdırılma olacaq?
      <input type="checkbox" id="delivery"  name="checkbox"  onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark-box"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bakıdaxili kuryer ilə (3 AZN)
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="kuryer" id="kuryer" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bakıdaxili taksi ilə (5 AZN)
      <input type="radio"  name="radio" value="taksi" id="taksi" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label id="deliveryRadio" class="container-radio">Bölgələrə poçtla (3 AZN)
      <input type="radio"  name="radio" value="poct" id="poct" onclick="calculateTotal()">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="totalPrice" style="padding:10px;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#ff0;
        ">
</div>
<div id="cartTotal">
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Təsdiq et</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default addToCart" id="addToCart" type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to add variable allTotal  into a grandTotal array when addToCart button clicked and then reset the form. It adds the datas but instead of adding new row it replaces the old data.

Comment: consider adding the `HTML` part so we could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @ths I added HTML codes. But please, consider that, calculation js code omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are redefining `grandTotal` each time you click. The following would be better :

```
var grandTotal = new Array;
for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButton.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCartButton[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        grandTotal.push(allTotal)
        var cartRowContents = '<table><tr><th>Xidmet adi</th><th>Cemi</th></tr>'
        var buttonClicked = document.getElementById('cartTotal')
        var serviceName = document.getElementById('service')
        for(k=0;k<grandTotal.length;k++){
            cartRowContents += '<tr><td>' +serviceName.value+'</td><td>' +grandTotal[k]+'</td></tr>' 
        }
        cartRowContents += '</table>';
        buttonClicked.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
    })
}
```

Do take the time to read about [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) in JS, it'll come in handy if you expand your script.

Comment: thank you very much. Now, it adds new row everytime button clicked, but when grandTotal changed table starts from row 1. Is it possible store every row inserted into the table? Btw, I will definitely read about scope :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you change the `type` of the button `addToCart` to `button` instead of `submit`, does it work better ?

Comment: I tried it, there is no change. Maybe I didn't explain well. For example, if grandTotal equals to 3, I click addToCart button three times and it adds three rows. After that if I change the selection and the grandTotal equals to 5 and I click addToCart button previous three rows are deleted and one row added with 5. I need to keep 3 rows of 3 and add one row of 5.

Comment: Understood ! I'm afraid it come from the change of selection (maybe it redefine `grandTotal` here ?) since nothing in the code you showed should do that. It may also be a scope issue as mentionned before. In both cases we'll need more script to find an answer, and it may be more practical to do so in another question. As a last improvement, you can switch the `cartRowContents += '</table>';` as I did in my answer, it'll make more correct html (and less buggy JS ^^) but shouldn't solve your problem.